# CSS: set width to width of parent

Tags: html, css

I am working with an `Angular` `mat-sidenav`. On the left I have a navigation and on the right simple comtent.

[image]

The place where we see `Navigation` should have a seperate `background-color` like the quickly painted image here. So to be 100% clear: I need the `div` with class `nav-title-container` to fill the parents width.

[image]

Yet when I try to do this, only the few pixels around the text are colored in. Probably because I am doing it wrong. I am also not that familiar with css (it has been quite some years). What simple stuff am I seeing over my head? I pressume the solution is quite simple yet I cannot find it on my own.

> HTML

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode='side' [(opened)]="opened">
       <div class="nav-title-container">
            <h4 class='nav-title'>Navigation</h4>
        </div>
       ....
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

> CSS

```
mat-sidenav {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 5em;
    padding-right: 5em;
}

.nav-title{
    width: 100%;
    
}

.nav-title-container{
    width: max-content; /* I Presume this should be something else, already tried 100% */
    background-color: goldenrod;
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid wheat;
}
```

Comment: Please Make clear What do you want. Elearly explain the question sir

Comment: I would advise you to study CSS Flexbox

Comment: You probably can't get full width, because of `padding-left` and `padding-right` you have on `mat-sidenav`. Best to move that padding on child elements if you need it. Another, but hacky, way is to add the same negative margin as you have for padding on `.nav-title-container`, e.g., `margin-left: -5em;`. And you probably want to set `.nav-title-container` `width` to 100% instead of `max-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this in your css:

```
mat-sidenav {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.nav-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.33em 5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-title--highlighted {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid wheat;
}
```

and this in your html:

```
    <mat-sidenav ...>
        <h4 class="nav-title nav-title--highlighted">Navigation</h4>
        <h4 class="nav-title">Statistics</h4>
    </mat-sidenav>
```

`h4` will have a 1.33 top and bottom margin unless you reset this with `margin: 0`. This number appears in the padding to allow you to color the background of the title. In general you want to add the padding on the element you want to see colored, most of the time it is the innermost component (in this case the `h4`). I added a cursor, you probably want the whole tag to be clickable later.

The containers were not needed.

[Try it on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-g8pohi)

Comment: Thanks, (one) of the issues was indeed the padding I enforced